# Having issue with sample_tools.init function for Google DFA API call

Tags: python, api, google-oauth, argparse

I am trying to initiate an API call with Google DFA without using a flow object (to get rid of the manual piece of inputting the access token in the code.) I have found a lot of sample codes to do this that start as such:

```
from oauth2client import client
import argparse
import sys
from apiclient import sample_tools


argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument(
    'profile_id', type=int, help='The ID of the profile to use')


def main(argv):
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'dfareporting', 'v2.1', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
      scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting',
               'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking']
```

Though this runs with no errors, it is not actually working as the 'service' and 'flags' object never get defined. I seem to be following the code exactly according to the many examples I have seen so I am at a loss of why this is not working.

Thank you to anyone who can help!!!

Comment: I am finding that I think I am getting an error with the argv argument as I have gotten this error a lot: NameError: name 'argv' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this by now, but that code is often preceded by a 'bootstrap' snippet that could look like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

When the script it run directly the global `__name__` is equal to the string `__main__` and so the `main` function is called with the argument `sys.argv` passed to the script. There will always be at least one argument passed to your script (the name of the script) but any other arguments you pass will also be available within the list `sys.argv`.

Answer (score -1):

In the Script you are actually importing apiclient, that should be ideally

```
from googleapiclient import smaple_tools
```